# Finding elements in common between two ksh or bash arrays efficiently

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, grep, ksh

I am writing a Korn shell script. I have two arrays (say, `arr1` and `arr2`), both containing strings, and I need to check which elements from `arr1` are present (as whole strings or substrings) in `arr2`. The most intuitive solution is having nested for loops, and checking if each element from `arr1` can be found in `arr2` (through `grep`) like this:

```
for arr1Element in ${arr1[*]}; do
    for arr2Element in ${arr2[*]}; do
        # using grep to check if arr1Element is present in arr2Element
        echo $arr2Element | grep $arr1Element
    done
done
```

The issue is that `arr2` has around 3000 elements, so running a nested loop takes a long time. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this in Bash.

If I were doing this in Java, I could have calculated hashes for elements in one of the arrays, and then looked for those hashes in the other array, but I don't think Bash has any functionality for doing something like this (unless I was willing to write a hash calculating function in Bash).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your Java solution using hashes would deal with substrings. Perhaps you should add some pseudocode to clarify?

Comment: @slim You're right - it would't deal with substrings, only with exact matches. I added that part just to see if someone could come up with an equivalent solution (for exact matches) in bash.

Comment: BTW, use `"${arr1[@]}"`, not `${arr1[*]}`. The latter splits words, expands globs, and does various other undesirable things.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks - made the same change in my answer

Comment: @slim, ...the quotes matter too -- `${arr1[@]}` behaves like `${arr1[*]}`. Compare `arr=( "hello world" "goodbye world" ); printf '%s\n' ${arr[@]}` with `arr=( "hello world" "goodbye world" ); printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"`

Comment: btw, bash, or ksh? And if ksh, *which* ksh? bash takes a lot of cues from ksh, but it's not a proper superset, and there's quite a lot of syntax that needs to be changed depending on which one is targeted. A question should specify one or the other, and -- especially with ksh -- be specific about which version (mksh and the other clones fall well behind real David Korn ksh on functionality!).

Comment: Umm, the preferred solution should be in ksh, but I thought I'd be able to translate bash to ksh, so I added bash as a tag to expand my options.

Comment: *which* ksh matters a lot. Not all widely used versions of ksh support associative arrays, for example, so a solution based on them may not translate (unless you're using proper David Korn ksh93 -- if you are, good on you).

Comment: BTW, `echo foo | grep bar` is *vastly* slower than `[[ foo = *bar* ]]`. Not that you need to do that at all, here.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 4.0 Bash has associative arrays:

```
$ declare -A elements
$ elements[hello]=world
$ echo ${elements[hello]}
world
```

You can use this in the same way you would a Java Map.

```
declare -A map
for el in "${arr1[@]}"; do 
    map[$el]="x"
done

for el in "${arr2[@]}"; do 
    if [ -n "${map[$el]}" ] ; then 
       echo "${el}"
    fi
done
```

Dealing with substrings is an altogether more weighty problem, and would be a challenge in any language, short of the brute-force algorithm you're already using. You could build a binary-tree index of character sequences, but I wouldn't try *that* in Bash!

Comment: However, I'd still say "use a modern scripting language" if you can. Python etc.

Comment: Thanks, but how would this help in comparing the elements in the two arrays, which is my main objective?

Comment: Added a demo. There might be a cleaner way than using the dummy value `"x"`

Answer (score 3):

[BashFAQ #36](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036) describes doing set arithmetic (unions, disjoint sets, etc) in bash with `comm`.

Assuming your values can't contain literal newlines, the following will emit a line per item in both arr1 and arr2:

```
comm -12 <(printf '%s\n' "${arr1[@]}" | sort -u) \
         <(printf '%s\n' "${arr2[@]}" | sort -u)
```

If your arrays are pre-sorted, you can remove the `sort`s (which will make this extremely memory- and time-efficient with large arrays, moreso than the `grep`-based approach).

Comment: how do you handle substrings?

Comment: I don't. The OP makes it clear in the comments on the question that matching substrings was a bug in their original implementation proposal, not a desired feature.

Comment: ah, ok, was going by the mention of substring in the question ... missed (and didn't fully understand) that bit buried down in the comments

Answer (score 2):

Since you're OK with using `grep`, and since you want to match substrings as well as full strings, one approach is to write:

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr2[@]}" \
  | grep -o -F "$(printf '%s\n' "${arr1[@]}")
```

and let `grep` optimize as it sees fit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `bash/awk` idea:

```
# some sample arrays

$ arr1=( my first string "hello wolrd")
$ arr2=( my last  stringbean strings "well, hello world!)

# break array elements into separate lines

$ printf '%s\n' "${arr1[@]}"
my
first
string
hello world

$ printf '%s\n' "${arr2[@]}"
my
last
stringbean
strings
well, hello world!

# use the 'printf' command output as input to our awk command

$ awk '
NR==FNR { a[NR]=$0 ; next }
{ for (i in a)
      if ($0 ~ a[i]) print "array1 string {"a[i]"} is a substring of array2 string {"$0"}" }
' <( printf '%s\n' "${arr1[@]}" ) \
  <( printf '%s\n' "${arr2[@]}" )

array1 string {my} is a substring of array2 string {my}
array1 string {string} is a substring of array2 string {stringbean}
array1 string {string} is a substring of array2 string {strings}
array1 string {hello world} is a substring of array2 string {well, hello world!}
```

- `NR==FNR` : for file #1 only: store elements into awk array named 'a'
- `next` : process next line in file #1; at this point rest of awk script is ignored for file #1; the for each line in file #2 ...
- `for (i in a)` : for each index 'i' in array 'a' ...
- `if ($0 ~ a[i] )` : see if a[i] is a substring of the current line ($0) from file #2 and if so ...
- `print "array1...` : output info about the match

---

A test run using the following data:

```
arr1 == 3300 elements
arr2 ==  500 elements
```

When all `arr2` elements have a substring/pattern match in `arr1` (ie, 500 matches), total time to run is ~27 seconds ... so the repetitive looping through the array takes a toll.

Obviously (?) need to reduce the volume of repetitive actions ...

- for an exact string match the `comm` solution by Charles Duffy makes sense (it runs against the same 3300/500 test set in about 0.5 seconds)
- for a substring/pattern match I was able to get a `egrep` solution to run in about 5 seconds (see my other answer/post)

Answer (score 0):

An `egrep` solution for substring/pattern matching ...

```
egrep -f <(printf '.*%s.*\n' "${arr1[@]}") \
         <(printf '%s\n'     "${arr2[@]}")
```

- `egrep -f` : take patterns to search from the file designated by the `-f`, which in this case is ...
- `<(printf '.*%s.*\n' "${arr1[@]}")` : convert `arr1` elements into 1 pattern per line, appending a regex wild card character (.*) for prefix and suffix
- `<(printf '%s\n' "${arr2[@]}")` : convert `arr2` elements into 1 string per line

When run against a sample data set like:

```
arr1 == 3300 elements
arr2 ==  500 elements
```

... with 500 matches, total run time is ~5 seconds; there's still a good bit of repetitive processing going on with `egrep` but not as bad as seen with my other answer (`bash/awk`) ... and of course not as fast the `comm` solution which eliminates the repetitive processing.